# RDLC report is not showing Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc

I have read all Question Answers I could find, but none of them solved my problem.

I have a class representing one row of my Data:

```
public class SimpleGeofenceReportDTO
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string SiteId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string StartDateTime { get; set; }

    public string EndDateTime { get; set; }

    public string GeofenceId { get; set; }

    public string GeofenceEvent { get; set; }

    public string EventDateTime { get; set; }

}
```

Reading the data from Db and converting to DTO list:

```
var reportList = geofenceReport.ToList();
                var report = new List<SimpleGeofenceReportDTO>();
                foreach (var geofenceRecord in reportList)
                {
                    report.Add(new SimpleGeofenceReportDTO()
                                   {
                                       AssetId = geofenceRecord.iAssetId.ToString(),
                                       CategoryId = geofenceRecord.iCategoryId.ToString(),
                                       EndDateTime = geofenceRecord.dtUTCDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                       GeofenceId = geofenceRecord.iGeofenceId.ToString(),
                                       GeofenceEvent = geofenceRecord.eEventCode == 6 ? "Geofence Enter" : "Geofence Exit"

                                   });
                }
```

My Report CS Code:

```
   var geofenceData = GETLISTOFGEOFENCEDTO();
    GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                        GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
                        GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.HyperlinkTarget = "_blank";
                        GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = sPath;
     GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
                            new ReportDataSource("GroupGeofenceSummaryReportDataTable", geofenceData ));
      GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
     GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

[image: Data Set in Report]

ASP.NET WEbPage Code:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />


    <div id="ReportContentDiv" runat="server">
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="GeofenceSummaryReportViewer" runat="server"
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana"
            WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="98%" Height="98%">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="TBReports\GeofenceSummaryReport.rdlc">
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
    <div id="ErrorDiv" runat="server">
        <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: small; font-weight: bold">Your session has expired, Please login again and then try to generate this report.</span>
    </div>
    </form>
```

I have debugged the code. Data is comming back from the DB, and also the report Div is showing on webpage but no data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your Report CS Code:

```
GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Try changing it to this:

```
GeofenceSummaryReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```